# How to copy the full row from one sheet to another if the column C is marked as Y

Tags: excel, vba

I have three sheets in a workbook and I want to copy all the rows from all the first three sheets into sheet 4 which has the column 'C' marked as Y.

Comment: Sl. No Testing Tasks Option
1 Test Design/Analysis Y
2 Test Case Preparation Y
3 Test Data Identification Y
4 Test Data Copy N
5 AI Code Deployment N                                                                              This is the sample sheet and I want to copy only the Y marked row into another sheet...Like this there are three sheets and I want to copy all the Y  marked rows in sheet 4 that which are to be appended from sheet1 to sheet2 and then sheet 3.

Comment: You need to put your above comment to the question body as I can see that is a kind of example data and helps clarifying your needs. On the other hand don't expect that anyone will write the solution from a to z: SO is not a free coding service. You did not show where you have stuck. If you are new to macros, you need to visit sites for tutorials. This time you need to know [how to copy/paste ranges](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-ranges/) and [how to write conditional logic](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-if/). After trying a couple of things you can issue your question where you have stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question, because I'm bored. 
The code below assigns the worksheets to filter to an array, loops thru the array, filters the range, then copies the visible cells in the filter data. If "A1" is empty; it will paste the copied data from each worksheet to `Range("A1")`, else it will paste the data to the first empty cell in "column A". Change the worksheet names as required.

```
Sub FltrPste()
Dim wb As Workbook, shtArr As Variant, wsDest As Worksheet, i As Long, lRow4 As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
shtArr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Sheet4")
lRow = wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LBound(shtArr) To UBound(shtArr)
        With wb.Sheets(shtArr(i)).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="y"
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
                If Range("A1") = "" Then
                    wsDest.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Else
                    wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
                .AutoFilter
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```